# Series Question $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4^n}{7^{n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I`m trying to check if the following series are convergent.
$$1)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4^n}{7^{n+1}}$$
$$2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{5^n}{4^{n+2}}$$
what I did so far for the first one is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4^n}{7^{n+1}} = q=\frac{4}{7}<1  \rightarrow \frac{\frac{4}{7}}{1-{\frac{4}{7}}}$$
for the next one is the same thing, I just need to check the positive series, if I will understand the first one I think the seond will be ok.
so I would like to get some advice, Thanks!

Comment: It's not right. Write the sum as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over 7}(4/7)^n$ first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution for the first one is only ever so slightly off. Here is a hint:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4^n}{7^{n+1}} = \dfrac{1}{7}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\biggr(\frac{4}{7}\biggr)^n$$
For the second one, notice that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{5^n}{4^{n+2}} = \dfrac{1}{16}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\biggr(\frac{5}{4}\biggr)^n$$
What do you notice about the term in the geometric series?

Answer (score 1):

The first series is a gemetric one: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4^n}{7^{n+1}}=\frac {4}{49} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^n}{7^{n }}=\frac {4}{49}  \frac{1}{1-4/7}=\frac{4}{21}.$$

The second series diverges because its terms do not tend to zero in absolute value: $\frac{5^n}{4^{n+2}}\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$.